# 'Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined' when rendering JSON from fetch call in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I've created an app using the create-react-app. I have a Golang HTTP server and I am sending a GET request using fetch, receiving a JSON in response. This part works perfectly. The problem arises with wanting to render this JSON. Right now I don't care for formatting. I just want to be able to print it.

With the this.setState line I get an error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

I've seen a lot of questions here on Stack Overflow and on other websites but I can't find any explanation for why this is happening.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        siteData: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Send GET request to Go server")
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/site", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            response.text().then(function(data) {
                console.log("Get response data: " + data);
                console.log(response);
                //siteData = JSON.parse(data);

                this.setState({
                    siteData: JSON.parse(data)
                });

            });
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: normally people dont call the API directly inside the componentdidMount. also try using arrow function for callbacks

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier I think it's OK to call APIs in componentDidMount. You can define service or other helper methods but I think they're generally called in componentDidMount. What do you suggest?

Comment: @bravemaster its fine, but normally you don't put API calls directly in the component as it cant be reused

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier In React, everything is a component. And one must call Api in order to fetch data unless it uses static mockup data. And that method should be called in componentDidMount. After data is fetched, those will be passed to child components as props. So it's okay and common to call api in componentDidMount. But hard-coding urls like the above code is a bad practice. What do you think?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier how would you suggest I improve upon the way and place I'm using fetch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the callback functions of the promises   `this` is not the same as the `this` of react component.

Use `Arrow function` in the callback to propagate the context of the react component to the callback function.

```
<your_code>.then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            response.text().then(data => {
                console.log("Get response data: " + data);
                console.log(response);
                //siteData = JSON.parse(data);

                this.setState({
                    siteData: JSON.parse(data)
                });

            });
        }
    })
```

Comment: How would you suggest I use this siteData variable in the render function?

Comment: once you setState `siteData` you will be able to access it from anywhere inside the component by `this.state.siteData`

Comment: When I try to .map the variable, I get an error saying it's not a function. :/

Comment: '.map' works only on Array. May be you are trying to `map` an array before it is available, please remember both `fetch` and `setState` are `asynchronous`

Comment: here is one of my sample snippet for working with `fetch` api in react:  https://codepen.io/mostafiz93/pen/KKpmPjM   You can set initial state to avoid `undefined` state data.

Comment: So I want to generate a table using the JSON that I've retrieved.That means accessing elements within the siteData variable. How would you suggest I do that?

Comment: set initial state to empty array, it will render nothing if you map, when the data is fetched it will be rendered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208631/discussion-between-sindhugauri-and-mostafiz-rahman).